# Minecraft plugin load failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I made a basic 1.19 plugin using spigot, and load it with paper. But it says load fail. This is the exception:

```
[20:50:56 ERROR]: [DirectoryProviderSource] Error loading plugin: File 'plugins\Real_Craft.jar' failed to load!
java.lang.RuntimeException: File 'plugins\Real_Craft.jar' failed to load!
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:59) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.lambda$registerProviders$2(DirectoryProviderSource.java:32) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:30) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:14) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.util.EntrypointUtil.registerProvidersFromSource(EntrypointUtil.java:14) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.PluginInitializerManager.load(PluginInitializerManager.java:100) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(Main.java:126) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main.main(Main.java:309) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        at io.papermc.paperclip.Paperclip.lambda$main$0(Paperclip.java:42) ~[app:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File 'plugins\Real_Craft.jar' is not a valid plugin file, cannot load a plugin from it!
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:54) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-483]
        ... 20 more
```

I tried to fix it from some ways to fix it, the tutorial I followed is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcFb0GO14zY, and I can't find errors in my code. here's my plugin.yml and main script

```
name: RealCraft
version: 1.0.0
author: knowscratcher
main: com.knowscratcher.realcraft.RealCraft
api-version: 1.19
```

and my main script is

```
package com.knowscratcher.realcraft;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class RealCraft extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE+"[RealCraft]:Plugin is enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"[RealCraft]:Plugin is disabled");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the plugin.yml file is on the jar file? Do you hvae maven or something?

Comment: No, 

plugin.yml
com
-knowscratcher
--realcraft
---Realcraft.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the plugin.yml file isn't on the jar, bukkit, spigot and paper cannot load the plugin**. You need to make sure to include it in the final jar. You can do it manually, but I don't recommend it.

**You should use a project manager to make the plugin.yml automatically included.**

**Here you can see an example of an extremely simple plugin that uses Maven**: https://github.com/OnyxianSoul/SendConsoleMessage .

If you set up your folder structure and pom.xml in the same way, and use maven to build your jar, your plugin jar will include the necessairy files, and will be loaded correctly.

Good luck

Comment: Try formatting the answer in a better way in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Is it better now? Do you have any specific suggestions?